# SublimePlayer inside AngularJS view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html5-video

I am trying to render a sublime player inside a dynamically loaded angularjs ui-view. My problem is that the HTML content I'm loading into the view comes from an ng-model.

For example, I have the model `content`, which stores the following code:

```
<video sublime-player id="sublime_player" poster="" width="980" height="551" data-name="test" data-uid="test-uid" preload="none">
    <source src="http://cdn.mydomain.com/myvideo.mp4" data-quality="hd" />
</video>
```

The `sublime-player` attribute on the video tag should point to a directive to render the player.

Sublime needs to be setup with the following code, to render the player:

```
sublime.ready(function(){
    sublime.prepare(attr.id, function(player) {
        // player is now ready.
        // 'sublime_player' is the video element's id
        var player = sublime('sublime_player');
    });
})
```

How can I run a directive that will run and render the sublime player when the `content` model is loaded?

Do I have to compile the `content` model in order for the directive to work?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've been able to make this work is by dynamically writing the video element to the dom *before* loading sublime. The only way to hold off the loading of sublime is to load it within the directive; This means you'll be calling it every time the template is loaded.

```
app.directive("sublime", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E', // Create <sublime></sublime> to use in template
        link: function($scope, element, attrs) {

            // Programmatically add sources or other attrs to <video> from your ngModel
            element.html('<video><source src="movie.ogg"></video>');

            // Capture new <video> in var
            var myVideoPlayer = element[0].children[0];

            sublime.load(); // Load Sublime
            sublime.ready(function(){ // Wait for init
                sublime.prepare(myVideoPlayer, function(player){ // Queue up player
                    console.log('Sublime Player Ready');
                });

                // Event Listeners & Analytics Here: 
                sublime.player(myVideoPlayer).on("start", function(){ /* Do Something */ });

            });
        }
    };
});
```

**NOTE:** Since implementing this, I can only get a few mobile devices to play this back. I'm still determining if it has to do with this implementation or some other conflict in my app.